# Unable to launch the installer

Tags: installation, crash, visual-studio

My visual studio installer is not coming up.

> Visual Studio Installer
>
> Unable to launch the installer.
>
> Error. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I fix it?

[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an old version of Microsoft .NET Framework, which is probably
the reason for the error. The solution is to update to the latest evrsion.

It would help to know your Windows version before recommending any download,
for an explanation of why Windows Update has not already done this update.

If there is no problem with the Windows version, the latest version today is 4.8,
and you may download it at microsoft
[Download .NET Framework 4.8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48).

If you are a developer, creating applications that run on .NET Framework,
you should rather download the Developer Pack.

Comment: to download it do i have to uninstall the one i have

Comment: It is backward compatible, so the latest is enough